# learn CNN Visualization with a Grad-CAM Demo

Tags: tensorflow

I am new to `tensorflow` for deep learning and interested in CNN visualization.

I read a paper (Grad-CAM: Visual Explanations from Deep Networks via Gradient-based Localization).

And I find demo from the [Github](https://github.com/insikk/Grad-CAM-tensorflow/blob/master/gradCAM_tensorflow_VGG16_demo.ipynb).

I run this demo, but there something wrong with me:

[image]

I try to address it with change tf's version, but that's in vain. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `_relu_grad` to `relu_grad` may resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try this https://github.com/cyberneuron/RT-CNN-Vis for Grad-CAM , it is a platform for real time CNN visualization. It particularly involves the Grad-CAM algorithm and it can run as a script - gradcam.py , the code should be quite clear to read.